# How is $s^2+(q_0-1)(s+r_0)$ obtained in Frobenius method proof in (Special Functions for Scientists and Engineers)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, frobenius-method

In **Special Functions for Scientists and Engineers**'s very first section in the proof of Frobenius method, the equation **(1.7)**
$a_0s(s-1)+a_0q_0s+a_0r_0=0$
is obtained as a special case for $i=0$ in the general case. After some steps the general case is obtained as

$a_i[(s+i)(s+i-1)+q_0(s+i)+r_o]$ **(1.11)**

**The next step is what confused me:**

> We now see that equation **(1.7)** reduces to
>   $a_0[s^2+(q_0-1)(s+r_o)]$

How can

$s(s-1)+q_0s+r_0$ $=$ $s^2+(q_0-1)(s+r_o)$ ?

Shouldn't **(1.12)** be

$s^2+s(q_0-1)+r_0$ ?

Comment: It seems as if you are right. Is there a next step, a conclusion from 1.12, so that one can see if it is simply a misprint or a continued error? -- It might help getting more attention if you put in front of your question that the general situation is the ODE $x^2y''(x)+xq(x)y'(x)+r(x)y(x)=0$.

Comment: You should give better references: e.g. at least provide the author; if possible, provide a link to the book;  if possible, provide a link to the relevant text. In this case, the book is [Special Functions for Scientists and Engineers, by W.W. Bell, Dover](https://www.amazon.com/Special-Functions-Scientists-Engineers-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B00DLYUOBW#reader_B00DLYUOBW) and the Look Inside feature of Amazon allows you to look at the relevant page. Finally, I believe it's a typo.